# Using brackets in cookie names (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

When attempting to write/read cookies that have brackets in the name, it seems like Rails can't handle this.  For example:

```
cookies["example[]"] = "value"
```

This causes the cookie name to be "example%5B%5D" instead of "example[]".  Similarly, if I already have a cookie set with the name "example[]", then it seems like Rails is unable to properly delete it via a call `cookies.delete "example[]"` since the `[` and `]` characters are being encoded.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Simple solution... don't use brackets in cookie names.

Comment: Does string escaping work? E.g. "example\\[\\]" ?

Comment: @Karl - unfortunately not. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this can only be done by [hacking the Rails core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094944/how-can-i-disable-url-encoding-of-cookies-in-rails). Sucks that the Rails developers implemented it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Th [rfc](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html) does not specify what all can be in the name of a cookie . All it says that the name needs to be text  . I guess rails is encoding the text and hence the brackets are becoming %5B%5D . I think its best to avoid such characters in Cookies .